# how can I transfer files to SD card of emulated device while developing Android app in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I develop Android app in Eclipse. I test it in emulator. This emulated device has emulated SD card. I want to put some files on this card. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select Device -> select the emulator (see step-1 in image)
- Select File Explorer -> SDCard-> Select Directory (DCIM) (see step-2
  in image)
- select Push a file OntoDevice image -> select the file -> click on
  Open button (see step-3 in image)
  see the attached image[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can push file into the Sd-card of emulators (Just check left/right arrow icon with mobile/floppy sign).

You find out the below view inside the `DDMS`, select a particular device from `devices` list, and then select `File Explorer`. (In short, steps are: **`DDMS -> device selection -> File Explorer`**)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch to DDMS perspective
2. Open File Explorer
3. Locate SD card(desired folder)
4. There is one icon - Push a file onto the device

Answer (score 0):

Go to `DDMS Perspective` in `Eclipse` or open the `ddms.bat` application in the `android-sdk/tools` folder. Select your emulator in the list, then go to `File -> Device -> File Explorer..` Select the `sdcard` and click the `Push file onto device icon` in the menu. This should work.